# Understanding how the Cantor set contains the point $4/9.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, cantor-set

Here is a statement from Bartle "Introduction to real analysis" that say that the Cantor set contains the point $4/9$ when $k=2$ and $n=2.$

> [image]

I know from the first Cantor set $F_1,$ that we removed the interval $(1/3, 2/3)$ but the statement above says that $4/9$ is in the cantor set, how is that? could someone explain this to me?

Comment: The Cantor set is the limit, so you could say something like "... the first approximation $F_1$ of the Cantor set...".

Comment: @SammyBlack yeah but $4/9$ is still away from $1/3$

Comment: True, $\tfrac{4}{9}$ is not in the Cantor set, since as you observe, it is removed upon the first approximation. This does not contradict the author's statement though, as he does not claim that *all* points of this form are included in the Cantor set.

Comment: @SammyBlack I see your point .... thank you! :)

Comment: All fish live in water but not everything that lives in water is a fish.   All elements of the Cantor set are of the form $\frac {2^k}{3^n}$, but not all things of the form $\frac {2^k}{3^n}$ are in the Cantor set.  .... $\frac 49$ is of the form, but it is *not* on of the endpoints and it is not in the Cantor set.  .... He merely said.  If it was in the Cantor Set, it is of the form.  He *never* said if it was the form it was in the Cantor Set.

Comment: @fleablood I see thank u!

Comment: Yeah, sloppy language. "These are all points of the form..." is not wrong, per se, but better to say "All of these are points of the form..." to get how the word "all" applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful parsing the language.

All endpoints of intervals that are in the Cantor set are of that form, but the author is *not* saying the converse, namely that all points of that form are endpoints of intervals in the Cantor set.